# Evento onclick en pantalla touch

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-5

estoy desarrollando un proyecto en laravel 5.5, el problema es que cuando quiero deslogearme y ejecutar el evento onclick en una pantalla touch no lo ejecuta ¿de que manera puedo hacerlo para que se ejecute en una pantalla tactil?

aquí esta el código

```html
<li>
       <ahref="{{ route('logout') }}"
       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                document.('logout-form').submit();">
       Salir
   </a>

   <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST"                                       style="display: none;">
       {{ csrf_field() }}
   </form>
</li>
```

Comment: ¿No sería `document.getElementById('logout-form').submit()`?

Comment: Deberías dejar un espacio también entre <a href="">

Comment: En el caso del touch, los taps son tratados equivalentemente como clicks. Es probable que tu código esté mal semánticamente y el navegador web deduzca lo que quieres hacer y lo haga incluso con errores. No obstante en el caso de navegadores en el móvil la mayoría no ofrecen este mecanismo de auto reparación de errores. Pueden ser tantas razones y hay muy poco código como para deducir univocamente el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así lo tengo yo y funciona:

```
<li>
     <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
          Salir
     </a>
     <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
     </form>
</li>
```